# Database Record not saving/persisting within a Rails test function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, persistent

I have an `update`-type method that I am trying to test in Rails using MiniTest and FactoryGirl. My problem is that although I can see that the update *is* happening correctly *within* the update function, it doesn't seem to carry over back into the test-function properly.

These is the objects we are working with, (`obj` is given a default `location` to start off with:

```
location1 = create :location
location2 = create :location
obj = create :object, location: location1
```

And then we call the `update` function, which takes `id`'s:

```
obj.update_location(obj.id, location2.id)
```

The `update` function:

```
def update_location(obj_id, loc_id)
    @obj = Object.find(obj_id)
    @obj.location_id = loc_id
    @obj.save
end
```

But when, back in the test file, I try to `assert` the change…

```
assert_equal obj.location_id, location2.id
```

...I get a failure. The console tells me that `obj.location_id` still equals `location1.id`! Why is this?

It seems that the `@obj.save` *is* working properly because I inserted `puts @obj.inspect` in the update-function and it outputs the correctly updated `location_id`.

I don't think it has to do with transaction-rollbacks because this is all taking place within a single test. (And I am under the impression that transaction rollbacks only happen in between tests).

In summary, my question is: **Why doesn't my update persist back into the rails MiniTest `test` function?**

EDIT: Here is the whole test:

```
test "update_location" do    
    location1 = create :location
    location2 = create :location

    #give the obj a starting `type`
    obj = create :obj, location: location1

    obj.update_location(obj.id, location2.id)   
    assert_equal obj.location_id, location2.id    
end
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see the entire test cycle before being able to think about it in any reasonable way. I'd also try `save!` to avoid eating exceptions.

Comment: I added the whole, and only, test function in the file. I am running only that file using `rake test test/models/obj_test.rb`

Comment: (@DaveNewton-Tried `save!`, didn't help...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue is resolved, and here is my understanding:

The issue was in how rails' ORM work. The original object 'obj' is loaded up with data from the DB when it is created…but later changes to the DB are not automatically stored to `obj`. I had thought that `obj.some_attribute` looks at the database for the record `obj` in order to find the attribute value--but in actuality I think that the attributes are simply loaded into the variable upon its creation and the database is NOT accessed if I call `obj.some_attribute` at a later point in time.

Normally, when an update is done through the variable itself, Rails knows to update the variable for you. So when you write `obj.some_attribute = 5`, and then later on write `obj.some_attribute`, Rails knows the value is supposed to be 5. But that Rails magic doesn't happen in this situation because it's not updating the record through the variable.

So what needs to be done is simply to `reload` the object from the database.

So `assert_equal obj.reload.location_id, location2.id` works!

Answer (score 0):

2 questions that might help you find an answer:

1. Why are you using an instance variable `@obj` instead of a local variable `obj`
2. Why do you have a special method just to update 1 column.  Would the [update_column](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) not work for you?

Comment: Tnx for the help! Here are the answers to your Q's…1-Not sure why that was used, but note that it is in a separate file from the tests (it's in `app/models/objects.rb`). 2-It's really part of a bigger method that does more things, I just simplified it for SO… :P

Comment: (I did try switching from `@obj` to just `obj`, to no avail.)